# https rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got the following htaccess, tried adding https rewrite/redirect - and it doesn't work, any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.svn/ - [F]

# rewrite traffic to HTTPS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working? Aside from an extra `RewriteEngine On`, your rule looks correct.

Comment: well, it doesn't do anything... if I put the https rule after the physical file lookup, than I just get internal server error...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to omit the [L] after your https rewriterule? Without it, if I request "http://myserver.com/something" it will first rewrite as "https://myserver.com/something" but then (I believe) continue on in the .htaccess file, subsequently using the internal rewrite to serve up "index.php" without actually redirecting the client. Though if the file requested does exist I'm not sure how Apache would handle that.